# Set Focus p-table to next input when inserting a value

Tags: angular, typescript

I got a p-table with inputs field in a component. After filling the input and sending the data with rest to database I want to set the focus from the input by clicking 'tab' to the next focusable input like in excel.

Do I need to do this by directives?

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" class="tableBody" let-rowData let-x="rowIndex" let-columns="columns">
   <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData" [ngClass]="rowData.editable != 'true' ? 'cell-color-gray2' : null" [hidden]="!showSubTotal(rowData)">
      <td *ngFor="let col of columns; let i = index" class="ui-resizable-column" [pEditableColumn]="rowData[col.field]" [pEditableColumnField]="rowData[col.field]">
         <p-cellEditor>
            <ng-template pTemplate="input">
               <div *ngIf="menuLabels.state=='editable' && rowData.editable=='true'">
                  <div *ngIf="col.field=='customEffort'" class="tableColumnRight">
                     <input #inputs type="text" ngDefaultControl [(ngModel)]="this.rowData.effort" autoResize="autoResize"
                            (focusout)="workaroundUpdateDataEffort({ data: rowData, costCenterNr: col.header.split(' ')[0], columns: columns }, x, i)"
                            (keydown.tab)="workaroundUpdateDataEffort({ data: rowData, costCenterNr: col.header.split(' ')[0], columns: columns }, x, i)"
                            (keydown.enter)="workaroundUpdateDataEffort({ data: rowData, costCenterNr: col.header.split(' ')[0] })"
                            (keydown.esc)="workaroundCatchEsc({ data: rowData })">
                  </div>
```

Comment: I think you want tab wise focusing on element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a directive, but you don't necessarily need to, you can also trigger that through an event. What you need is a reference to the HTML element you want to focus on. You do this by using a ViewChild:

```
@ViewChild('tab') inputEl:ElementRef;
```

In order to make that work, you have to set a ref-id in your html:

```
<tr #tab> <!-- element that holds the loop -->
```

Now, somewhere in your code, where you call the REST service:

```
onYourEvent(index) {
  restService.sendData().subscribe((res) => {
    // do something with the received data
    // then set the focus to the next element:
    const inputs = this.inputEl.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('input');
    if (inputs.length > index + 1) {
      inputs[index + 1].focus();
    }
  });
}
```

Here is a [demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-set-focus)

Comment: I try to focus the element, but it is still not working. Just in case i described my problem not properly. I got a input field in a p-Table and e.g. after pressing the TAB key, the frontend sends via REST data and THEN the next input field to the right should be focused, so I can guarantee useracceptance.

Comment: Ok. Do you get into the restDoneEventHandler? You can check e.g. by printing to the console, just to test. Then I guess you set the loaded data to the input and after that you want to focus the next element. So make sure, that the restDoneEventHandler is executed after you set the data. Otherwise it's possible that the first input gets the focus back, because the data changed.

Comment: First thanks for your help until now. I can access the handler, but unfortunately it won't focus the next input. I just checked the DOM tree of the inputs. My DOM tree is something like this:
TD -> CELLEDIT -> DIV -> DIV -> INPUT. So the loop iterates with celledit, not with input.
Is it possible to solve my problem by manually navigating through the elements?

Comment: yes, just make sure, the view child is outside the loop and then you can use the queryselector in order to find the inputs. See the edit.

Comment: So the only thing I can achieve right now is to display the array of the <tr> with their <td> in it. But I can't still access it with .focus()... Do you need more info?

Comment: I added a demo on stackblitz

Comment: The inputs array contains only my input element, which I try to change. There aren't all input elements in list. I tried now to access all elements, but can't access them.
Your stackblitz demo works, but that's executed with default table, maybe there is a difference because I am using p-Table from primeng?

Comment: Try to move the #tab (the view reference) to the parent or parent of parent and so on.

Comment: I can access this td list now: imgur.com/a/5n8iz3Z
This list contains all inputs from the header and the input I try to change, but not the following inputs